# boost compilation fails on Windows due to mt.exe failure

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to compile several libraries from boost and when the mt.exe tool tries to generate the manifest file it fails and the generated binaries (lib and dll) are removed and I can't get them when the compilation has finished.

```
mt : general error c101008d: Failed to write the updated manifest to the 
resource of file "D:\project\uniVision-x86-
Windows\_Sandbox_BUILD\boost\boost-1.58.0-
build\boost\bin.v2\libs\regex\build\msvc-12.0\debug\asynch-exceptions-
on\threading-multi\boost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.dll". The operation failed.

    if exist "D:\project\uniVision-x86-Windows\_Sandbox_BUILD\boost\boost-
1.58.0-build\boost\bin.v2\libs\regex\build\msvc-12.0\debug\asynch-
exceptions-on\threading-multi\boost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.dll.manifest" (
        call 
"C:\Users\danielh\AppData\Local\Temp\b2_msvc_12.0_vcvarsall_x86.cmd" >nul
mt -nologo -manifest "D:\project\uniVision-x86-
Windows\_Sandbox_BUILD\boost\boost-1.58.0-
build\boost\bin.v2\libs\regex\build\msvc-12.0\debug\asynch-exceptions-
on\threading-multi\boost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.dll.manifest" "-
outputresource:D:\project\uniVision-x86-Windows\_Sandbox_BUILD\boost\boost-
1.58.0-build\boost\bin.v2\libs\regex\build\msvc-12.0\debug\asynch-
exceptions-
on\threading-multi\boost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.dll;2"
    )

...failed msvc.manifest.dll D:\project\uniVision-x86-
Windows\_Sandbox_BUILD\boost\boost-1.58.0-
build\boost\bin.v2\libs\regex\build\msvc-12.0\debug\asynch-exceptions-
on\threading-multi\boost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.dll D:\project\uniVision-
x86-Windows\_Sandbox_BUILD\boost\boost-1.58.0-
build\boost\bin.v2\libs\regex\build\msvc-12.0\debug\asynch-exceptions-
on\threading-multi\boost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.lib D:\project\uniVision-
x86-Windows\_Sandbox_BUILD\boost\boost-1.58.0-
build\boost\bin.v2\libs\regex\build\msvc-12.0\debug\asynch-exceptions-
on\threading-multi\boost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.pdb...
...removing D:\project\uniVision-x86-Windows\_Sandbox_BUILD\boost\boost-
1.58.0-build\boost\bin.v2\libs\regex\build\msvc-12.0\debug\asynch-
exceptions-on\threading-multi\boost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.dll
...removing D:\project\uniVision-x86-Windows\_Sandbox_BUILD\boost\boost-
1.58.0-build\boost\bin.v2\libs\regex\build\msvc-12.0\debug\asynch-
exceptions-on\threading-multi\boost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.lib
...removing D:\project\uniVision-x86-Windows\_Sandbox_BUILD\boost\boost-
1.58.0-build\boost\bin.v2\libs\regex\build\msvc-12.0\debug\asynch-
exceptions-on\threading-multi\boost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.pdb
...skipped <pD:\project\uniVision-x86-
Windows\_Sandbox_BUILD\boost\stage\lib>boost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.dll for 
lack of <pD:\project\uniVision-x86-Windows\_Sandbox_BUILD\boost\boost-
1.58.0-build\boost\bin.v2\libs\regex\build\msvc-12.0\debug\asynch-
exceptions-on\threading-multi>boost_regex-vc120-mt-gd-1_58.dll...
```

Comment: In the past, not building boost, I have seen issues with mt.exe where anti-virus software would block mt.exe from altering a file. In those cases pausing the anti-virus on-demand scanning fixed the problem.